# Ubuntu 18 - package mismatch ("libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol: g_log_structured_standard")

Tags: gnome, dependencies, gnome-shell, gtk3

I have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18, (Bionic) from Ubuntu 16 (Xenial), and practically no GUI or windowing is working.
I think the problem is caused by package mismatch.
Here is some information:

> $ gedit
>   gedit: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: undefined symbol:
>   g_log_structured_standard
>
> $ gnome-system-monitor
>   gnome-system-monitor: symbol lookup error:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgiomm-2.4.so.1: undefined symbol:
>   g_application_set_option_context_description
>
> $ dpkg -l gnome-shell
>   ii gnome-shell 3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
>
> $ lsb_release -a
>   Distributor ID: Ubuntu; Description: Ubuntu 18.04
>   LTS; Release: 18.04; Codename: bionic
>
> $ uname -a
>   Linux 4.15.0-23-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
>   GNU/Linux
>
> $ dpkg -s libgtk-3-0
>   Version: 3.22.30-1ubuntu1
>   Provides:
>   gtk3-binver-3.0.0
>
> How should I fix the dependencies?
>   Suspecting glib2, I have now
>   separately installed (using dpkg):
>   libglib2.0-0_2.56.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb,
>   libglib2.0-dev_2.56.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb, and:
>   libglib2.0-dev-bin_2.56.1-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb
>   - with no errors, but
>   that didn't seem to help.

Note: cross-posted here:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/ubuntu-18-package-mismatch-libgtk-3-so-0-undefined-symbol-g_log_structured_standard-4175634876/

Comment: Does `ldd $(which gedit)` shed any light? (perhaps `libglib-2.0.so.0` not resolving to where you expect)?

Comment: I recommend to install SSH to this system and connect to it from other PC with internet browser (to visit AskUbuntu and http://packages.ubuntu.com).